# Is it necessary to use constructor in override method in python

Tags: python, inheritance

I have a class `A` and there are 2 methods `X` and `Y` in it
and then I make another class `B` which inherits the class `A`

Now I want to override the function `Y` but I am confused whether there is need to call the constructor again in class `B` or directly I can override the method

Comment: Overriding "virtual" or "open" functions is not directly related to calling of its base class constructor(s). Constructors are to initialise the object. Methods are called after the object is initialised. Having to call a constructor depends if the base class constructor needs an argument to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the method.

For some reason if you need to call the superclass's method as well, you can use `super`:

```
class B(A):
    def Y(self):
        from_A = super().Y()  # this calls `A.Y()`
        # Do stuffs
```

While we're at this, if you override the initializer (`__init__`), the same rule applies -- you can have `B` has his own set of rules, and if you want to also leverage `A`'s `__init__` use `super` like I shown. The same rule applies for other methods as well.